# Single word for "Number of times which sonething. be used"

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a noun to describe "Number of times which something be used".

Eg: `A machine have been used for 10 times, it needs to be cleaned up.`

In this situation

____ is 10 times, What is the word to represent the 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

*The machine should be serviced after 10 uses.* However, it is more likely that a machine service would happen on a regular schedule rather than after a number of uses. *The machine should be serviced every 6 months.*

Answer (score 0):

In English, when referring to a number of times, special adverbs are generally reserved for one (called ***once***) or two times (called ***twice***); the word *thrice* is sometimes used as a logical progression to represent three times.

Apart from these, there are no special adverbs for other numbers, such as the number ten in your case. Instead, you would have to say ***ten times***. It's certainly annoying that the pattern does not continue past three times, but language can evolve - who knows, we might be saying "fource" in a hundred years (though let's leave that to the future)!

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for a word meaning "ten times" but rather for a word meaning "times used" which could be modified by or associated with "ten" or another number. The statements in this answer are all correct, but I dont think it anwers the question asked.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Ah, I see. After looking again at the question it seems that the OP was looking for something different. My mistake.